# Creating a Custom Container Visual for PowerBI

Tags: javascript, html, css, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I currently have a table on PowerBI that has columns generated via field parameter slicers. The slicers are on the left of the dashboard, and I select fields from the slicers, which add/remove columns on the table. As I develop this dashboard, the number of slicers will increase, creating a cluttered dashboard.
This issue can be solved by hard-coding a "Container" with Power BI SDK.

The purpose of the "Container" will be to act as an expandable panel with scrolling up/down capabilities. I will add the list of slicers I created inside this container. When I click on the container icon on PowerBI, it should open up an expandable panel with all of the slicers. I can scroll up and down to find the slicer I need and use the slicer within the panel. And when I am done using the slicers in the panel, I can close out of it and return to just viewing my table that has the added/removed columns based on what I selected on my slicer.

To create my container, I installed powerbi-visuals-tools via CMD. Then, ran the following command pbiviz new container - to create the container folder with all of the code that I will need to configure.

```
npm install -g powerbi-visuals-tools
pbiviz new container
```

[Container Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDmNJ.jpg)

I had to modify 3 files: Visual.ts, capabilities.json, and pbiviz.json & create 2 new files index.html, styles.css.

Visual.ts :

```
 import powerbi from "powerbi-visuals-api";

export class Visual implements powerbi.extensibility.IVisual {
  private container: HTMLElement;
  private expandButton: HTMLElement;

  constructor(options: powerbi.extensibility.VisualConstructorOptions & { element: HTMLElement }) {
    this.container = document.createElement("div");
    this.container.className = "container";
    options.element.appendChild(this.container);

    this.expandButton = document.createElement("div");
    this.expandButton.className = "expand-button";
    this.expandButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.container.classList.toggle("expanded");
    });
    options.element.appendChild(this.expandButton);
  }

  public update(options: powerbi.extensibility.VisualUpdateOptions & { dataViews: powerbi.DataView[] }) {
    this.container.innerHTML = "";

    const dataView: powerbi.DataView = options.dataViews[0];
    const selectedFields: powerbi.DataViewCategoryColumn[] =
      dataView.categorical?.categories || [];

    this.renderSlicerDropdown(selectedFields);
  }

  private renderSlicerDropdown(fields: powerbi.DataViewCategoryColumn[]) {
    const slicerDropdown = document.createElement("select");
    slicerDropdown.className = "slicer-dropdown";
    slicerDropdown.multiple = true;

    fields.forEach((field: powerbi.DataViewCategoryColumn) => {
      const option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = field.source.displayName;
      option.value = field.source.queryName;

      slicerDropdown.appendChild(option);
    });

    this.container.appendChild(slicerDropdown);
    this.enableScrolling();
  }

  private enableScrolling() {
    this.container.classList.add("scrollable");
  }
}
```

Styles.css :

```
#container {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  .expand-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .expand-button:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
  }
  
  #container.expanded {
    max-height: none;
  }
```

Index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Power BI Custom Visual</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script src="visual.ts" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

pbiviz.json:

```
{
    "visual": {
      "name": "container",
      "displayName": "container",
      "guid": "containerFC8829B70A714887A31CE541968A816C",
      "visualClassName": "Visual",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "supportUrl": "",
      "gitHubUrl": ""
    },
    "apiVersion": "5.1.0",
    "author": {
      "name": "",
      "email": ""
    },
    "assets": {
      "icon": "assets/icon.png"
    },
    "style": "./src/styles.css",
    "capabilities": "./capabilities.json",
    "dependencies": null,
    "stringResources": []
  }
```

capabilities.json

```
{
  "dataRoles": [
    {
      "displayName": "Fields",
      "name": "Fields",
      "kind": "GroupingOrMeasure"
    }
  ],
  "objects": {
    "general": {
      "displayName": "General",
      "properties": {
        "formatString": {
          "displayName": "Format String",
          "type": {
            "formatting": {
              "formatString": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "container": {
      "displayName": "Container",
      "properties": {
        "expanded": {
          "displayName": "Expanded",
          "type": {
            "bool": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "fieldPanel": {
      "displayName": "Field Panel",
      "properties": {
        "fields": {
          "displayName": "Fields",
          "type": {
            "field": {
              "kind": "GroupingOrMeasure",
              "groupName": "Fields"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": [],
  "custom": {
    "author": "",
    "displayName": "Custom Container",
    "supportUrl": "",
    "visual": {
      "name": "customcontainer",
      "displayName": "Custom Container",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "capabilities": {
        "script": "visual.ts",
        "style": "styles.css"
      },
      "apiVersion": "2.3.0"
    }
  }
}
```

In visual.ts, I've added a CSS class "scrollable" to the container element, which enables scrolling within the container. Additionally, I've introduced a new CSS class "expanded" for the container, which allows it to act as an expandable panel when the user clicks on the expand button.

Now, when I am attempting to package the files to create my custom visual via CMD, I am getting this error:

```
error  should NOT have additional properties
error  Invalid capabilities
```

Anyone know what I can do to fix this?